# Identify duplicate rows with pandas and convert such rows into one row, creating a new columns as a result

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataset of stations

```
    map_id  longitude   latitude  zip_code
0   40830 -87.669147  41.857908     60608
1   40830 -87.669147  41.857908     60608
2   40120 -87.680622  41.829353     60609
3   40120 -87.680622  41.829353     60609
4   41120 -87.625826  41.831677     60616
```

As you can see, the first four rows are duplications and it is not an accident. They are the same stations, which are treated as separate stations of different lines.

I would like to eliminate such duplicates (it can be 2 or even 5 rows for some stations) and treat it as one station.

Moreover, I would like to create a new column "Hub", where aggregated rows will be treated a hub station. For example, as a boolean (0 for a regular station, 1 for a hub).

The desired output for the sample above with two cases of duplication -> transformed into 3 rows with 2 hubs.

```
    map_id  longitude   latitude  zip_code    hub
0   40830 -87.669147  41.857908     60608      1
1   40120 -87.680622  41.829353     60609      1
1   41120 -87.625826  41.831677     60616      0
```

I appreciate any tips!

Comment: have tried `DataFrame.drop_duplicates`?

Comment: Thanks, but It does not solve my question, how will know which hubs do I have then? Maybe if I use this one, I need to create an extra column first, mark duplicates as hubs somehow, and only then drop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.groupby(['map_id','longitude','latitude','zip_code']).size().reset_index(name='hub')

df['hub'] = df['hub'].replace(1,0).apply(lambda x:min(x,1))
```

Output

```
   map_id  longitude   latitude  zip_code  hub
0   40120 -87.680622  41.829353     60609    1
1   40830 -87.669147  41.857908     60608    1
2   41120 -87.625826  41.831677     60616    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you want to drop duplicates and assign certain zipcodes as hub. If so, I would drop duplicates and use `np.where` to assign hubs. I included a non existent opcode to demonstrate how you can do this if more than one zipcode is designated as a hub

```
import numpy as np



df2=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['map_id','longitude','latitude','zip_code'], keep='first')
conditions=df2['zip_code'].isin(['60616','60619'])
df2['hub']=np.where(conditions,0,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this logic works also, thanks a ton. I wish I can accept this as an answer too, but I think it will be fair for the first answer. Really appreciate your help!